# Moved a steam radiator, wont heat up

Tags: steam

Just moved a 2 pipe steam radiator about 10 feet so that I can put a door where it was. Pipework went smoothly. Turned heat on, it pressurized, but that pipe isn't heating up. This pipe branches from another right where it meets the furnace. The other branch is heating. Did I miss something? Is there an air issue or something?

Comment: Can you find any air bleeder valves/bolts near the top?  You did double check any shut off valves were turn on again?

Comment: valves are back on - do you need to bleed air from steam radiators? there ARE bleeder valves, yes.

Comment: Possible those bleeder valves are struck/not working/blocked as they should(found from google).  They are suppose to be automatic.

Comment: aha. I'll take a look.